# How to scrape other url and append data to set of items - Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I try to add the prediction of yesterday and tomorrow to the set of data and i dont see how to pass the url of yesterday and tomorrow, i try with append but this add the information to my actual fields and i need add each one to he's respective field on the db

```
def parse_daily(self, response):
        morePredictions = response.css('div.more-data > a::attr(href)').extract()
        yesterday = response.css('main > nav > a:nth-child(1)::attr(href)').extract_first()
        tomorrow = response.css('main > nav > a:nth-child(3)::attr(href)').extract_first()
        morePredictions.append(yesterday)
        morePredictions.append(tomorrow)

        item = {
                'name':sign,
                'Description':descripcion,
            }

        for signurl in morePredictions:
            absolute_url = response.urljoin(signurl)
            yield response.follow(absolute_url,meta={"signUrl": signurl, "signName": sign, 'item': item}, callback=self.parse_extras)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the full code? You can use 'start_urls'. I assume that both links have the same html structure so with start_urls it will scrape both urls with the same parse method. I think you need to change your logic.